# VBA optimize performance for 3 loops

Tags: vba, excel, loops, optimization

First I wish to check if the value in in each row of column D of "Sheet1" matches any row of column A of "Accepted". If there is a match, I would like to copy the value in column B of that row of "Sheet1" into column D of "Accepted".

However, as there are 2 possible values in column B of "Sheet1", I would like to split the values into two columns of "Accepted" - Columns D and E. Hence, the next loop, if the value in column D of "Accepted" is not "Restricted", then copy that value into Column E and remove content of Column D.

The code works fine in that it helps me to achieve my goal, however, the process is taking too long, and after some investigation I found out that the delay only occurs with the last loop. I was wondering if I could speed up this process, thanks!

```
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim k As Long

'to speed up the VBA code
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With


AcceptedLastRow = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Accepted").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Sheet1LastRow = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For j = 1 To AcceptedLastRow
        For i = 1 To Sheet1LastRow
            If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 4).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Accepted").Cells(j, 1).Value Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Accepted").Cells(j, 4).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value    
            End If
        Next i
    Next j

'to transfer recognised status to the recognised column and to remove from restricted column
'I think this is the section which contributes to the lag/delay
Restrictedlastrow = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Accepted").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For k = 9 To Restrictedlastrow
        If ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Accepted").Cells(k, 4).Value <> "Restricted" Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Accepted").Cells(k, 4).Copy ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Accepted").Cells(k, 5)
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Accepted").Cells(k, 4).ClearContents
        End If
    Next k


'to reset settings back to normal
With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
```

Comment: If this is working code looking for improvements all around, then it's a [codereview.se] post that just needs a better title (one that roughly describes what the code does), and will do great over there. On SO this kind of question is generally viewed as *too broad*.

Comment: The most obvious thing to me is the reference to the Cells.Value. You can create a references to `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets` (Sheet1, Accepted) and use them. That will save maybe a dozen op codes for each loop iteration. `Dim wksSh1 As WorkSheet; Set wksSh1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")`; then use directly `wksSh1.Cells`

Comment: I'm willing to leave it for `Code Review`, but I can't help expressing my big astonishment for *"I found out that the delay only occurs with the last loop"*.

Comment: Would likely be much faster using `Application.Match()` than a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Accepted").Cells(k, 4).Copy ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Accepted").Cells(k, 5)
```

Use

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Accepted").Cells(k, 5) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Accepted").Cells(k, 4)
```

Copy is an expensive operation. Since you seem to be interested only in a value of a cell, assign it directly (like you did in the previous loops).

Comment: oh wow, that works perfectly. Didn't know about the hefty copy function, thanks a bunch!